# Python While Loop Condition Evaluation

Tags: python, while-loop

Say I have the following loop:

```
i = 0
l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
while i < len(l):
    if something_happens:
         l.append(something)
    i += 1
```

Will the `len(i)` condition being evaluated in the while loop be updated when something is appended to `l`?

Comment: If that's your code, it'll never exit for a different reason: at the beginning of the loop, i < len(l). As the loop continues, l can only get *bigger,* and i stays the same.

Comment: @orjac i think he omitted the "i" increment on purpose for the sake of brevety

Comment: yes... i know that you have to increment i.

Comment: I assumed that, if it's worth asking SO, he'd tried it and the loop never exited -- which is why I was looking for other bugs. ;)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes it will.

Answer (score 3):

Your code will work, but using a loop counter is often not considered very "pythonic".  Using `for` works just as well and eliminates the counter:

```
>>> foo = [0, 1, 2]
>>> for bar in foo:
        if bar % 2: # append to foo for every odd number
            foo.append(len(foo))
        print bar

0
1
2
3
4
```

If you need to know how "far" into the list you are, you can use `enumerate`:

```
>>> foo = ["wibble", "wobble", "wubble"]
>>> for i, bar in enumerate(foo):
        if i % 2: # append to foo for every odd number
            foo.append("appended")
        print bar

wibble
wobble
wubble
appended
appended
```